# Time format is not recognized in snowflake

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table field in below format in snowflake. While trying to_date(), to_timestamp() function, its erring out with error message as - Timestamp '8/05/2018 9:03:53 PM' is not recognized.

Format - '8/05/2018 9:03:53 PM'

Comment: Please update the question with the complete to_timestamp() command you are using. Does the format you are providing in this function match the format of the string?

Comment: The field is of type varchar. When try 
select to_timestamp(modified_date) from table; we are getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the format in the TO_TIMESTAMP as follows:

`to_timestamp('8/05/2018 9:03:53 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') -- assumes MM/DD/YYYY`

or

`to_timestamp('8/05/2018 9:03:53 PM','DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') -- assumes DD/MM/YYYY`

Answer (score 0):

The format you are using is ambiguous, is it 8th May or August 5th?

Due to the above we don't support that date format.

For more information have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#date-formats)